# Удаление метки [.hpp]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки

Нужно удалить метку [.hpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.hpp) как не имеющую никакого смысла. Там было 4 вопроса, из которых я её удалил. Осталось сжечь саму метку.

Comment: сама удалится через какое-то время

Comment: @Grundy, какой-нибудь неофит в это время может вопрос с ней задать, мы её пропустим и она продолжит жить — нет, нам нужны костры инквизиции.

Comment: Garbage collector уже вышел на охоту. Ровно в полночь он настигнет метку и сожрёт её с потрохами.

Comment: @NickVolynkin в серверную полночь? Надо успеть задать вопрос, пока метка не превратилась в тыкву. Хотя ... можно и заново её создать при достаточной репутации :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, т.е. если у метки нет вопросов, то в 24 часа она аннигилирует?

Comment: @ixSci ага, вместе с двумя описаниями )